# Need more than 200 Cassandra tables per keyspace

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

Hi I am new to Cassandra and using DataStax Astra DB on AWS.
Problem I am facing is for each table we have different where clauses for different columns hence the modelling was done based upon the queries, (meaning multiple tables with same data but different clustering columns for query support.). This approach was working great till we reached [200 tables per keyspace guardrail limitation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/plan/planning.html#_tables).
One solution was to use SAI indexes however there is a limitation that I cant create more than 100 index per keyspace per cluster.
What is the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Aaron about 200 tables rarely being an issue but in addition to his answer, 200 is a soft limit that works in almost all cases.

To the uninitiated, more than 200 tables seems excessive but it's hard to know without getting to know your use case a bit deeper.

I'm reluctant to recommend you request for the limit to be increased without having intimate knowledge of your environment so I would suggest you reach out to them and request to be put in touch with one of the architects to discuss your requirements. Cheers!

Comment: Yes both of your answers make sense. I started with one keyspace for my spring-boot based microservice however I reached the 200 tables limit. better way of doing it would be for each module use a keyspace and storage index for easier data modelling. could you please share any spring-boot cassandra based reference it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious as to why so many tables are needed and are they really all for the same application?  Each application or service should have its own keyspace, so that 200 table limit shouldn't *usually* be a problem.

What you'll probably want to do is to create a new keyspace.  That will allow you to create more tables.

Comment: Aron, all 200 tables are part of one application. The reason we have created 200 tables  is because most of our api has different search criterias (query different columns eg. user table has name, email, phone, activestatus. so have replicated table user_by_email, user_by_name, user_by_phone & user_by_active_status). that is the reason lets say for 30 apis we actually  have let's say 30*4=120 tables. once solution to overcome this was to use SAI (storage attach index) however there seems to be a limitation where we can create only 100 indexes per cluster. I think data modelling is messed up.